# does the flat pre-cover need to exist for a left module?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, projective-module, injective-module

All modules do have the flat cover by a result from the year 2001.
What can be a ring $R$ and a left $R$-Module $M$ which doesn't have (a/the) **flat pre-cover** ? How can I construct such $R$ and left module $M$ over this $R$ ? Are all flat pre-covers of a fixed $M$ unique up to an iso ?

[Enochs, Edgar. "Flat covers and flat cotorsion modules." Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 92.2 (1984): 179-184.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DU3T.jpg)

[Bican, Ladislav, Robert El Bashir, and Edgar Enochs. "All modules have flat covers." Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society 33.4 (2001): 385-390.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBx4t.jpg)

Comment: I've replaced the inline images with citations linked to the images you posted. Please do not include enormous images inline in posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every flat cover is already a flat precover, because it is just a precover  with an extra condition.

I think the extra condition does allow you to prove that the precover is unique. For, if you had two precovers and found arrows going in opposite directions between them, then by composing the two (in both orders) you get an endomorphisms, and the extra condition says these endomorphisms are an isomorphisms. That would mean the original two maps were isomorphisms between the two precovers.

Since Bican, Bashir and Enochs proved that every module has a flat cover,  what you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: Right, so **pre**-covers do not immediately need to be unique ? Are they unique after all ?

Comment: @user122424 As far as I can see, for modules over a ring with identity, there is no difference between flat precovers and flat covers.  There  may be differences in other categories.

Comment: How could you prove that condition from my first source, that only auto's may fit into the second diagram in place of $\psi$ ?

Comment: @user122424 I think I already outlined a solution in my post above.... maybe refresh the page?

Comment: You have said **the extra** condition. So you may fail to have it, right ?

Comment: @user122424 I just meant the _definition_ has an extra condition. Whether or not it is superfluous, as I think it is in this case, is the key.